# SQL Injection not working on SQL injection vulnerable forms?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I have the following code, which is vulnerable to SQL injection(I think?):

```
$IDquery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `ID` FROM users WHERE username=$usernamelogin");
```

I don't escape the `$usernamelogin`, and that is not a parameterized query. This obviously needs to be fixed, you don't need to point that out, that isn't what this question is about. Before I fix it, I want to make sure I understand how an SQL injection works as well as possible. So, I tried creating a table named "droptable" and inputting the following into the username input:

```
x; DROP TABLE droptable;
```

Which I believe should input this SQL query:

```
SELECT `ID` FROM users WHERE username=x; DROP TABLE droptable;
```

However, droptable still exists, and the rows in it are untouched. Could anybody tell me why?

Comment: For when you do start making it secure after your testing, you're half way there as you use mysqli. Just switch to prepared statements and you're good. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli_query() doesn't support multiple query execution.

Comment: So how is this form vulnerable to SQL injection then?

Comment: sql injection doesn't mean "multiple query execution". if you managed to inject some code into query - it is vulnerable to injection

Comment: Oh, I see. Something like `x' or 'username'=$username` could be put into it, but this specific injection doesn't work. Does that mean dropping a table(and other functions, if they aren't already called in the query) are impossible with modern SQL injections?

Comment: I'm just trying to gain a fuller understanding of the concept. None of the texts I had read had pointed out that multiple queries weren't supported(except the manual, and I missed it there), so that's something new.

Comment: You **still** confuse certain query (used as a mere example) which **doesn't matter** with general concept. Again: a concept of SQL injection is about injecting code, not dropping tables.

Comment: I wouldn't understand graphing if I had never drawn an example graph from an equation, learning by example just seems logical to me.

Comment: But you wouldn't draw always the always the same graph out of different equations, would you?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have quotes around `$usernamelogin` so when you supply a string that would produce an error. Either add quotes or supply a number

Comment: The SQL injection does not seem to work even with quotes. I actually took out the quotes thinking they might be somehow preventing the injection.

Comment: Do the same thing you're doing in the question but instead of x put a number

Comment: I tried:
`32; DROP TABLE droptable;`

but it still didn't drop the table?